# How can I make a distributed shared transactional memory in a Azure webfarm?

Tags: .net, azure

I have a REST Web service running in a azure webfarm, that I need to protect against replay attachs.

Each request contains a unique [Cryptographic nonce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce) (a token that is only allowed once) within a few minutes.

Right now I use a database to create a entry with the nonce as primary key. This means that if one webserver can insert the row in the database I'm sure that no other webserver has received a request with the same nonce. Actually I use table storage  (with rowkey/partitionkey as primarykey)... and not SQL Azure.

My problem is that table storage is pretty slow (easily takes 20-30ms to insert a row), and I'm looking for a faster solution.

Is there a distributed shared transactional memory library for .NET? It's important that I don't introduce a single point of failure (eg. with a in memory database running on one server).

Bonus: Because this is running In Azure I don't know the names or IP address of my servers, and the number of servers in the webfarm changes quite often.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AppFabric Caching Service perhaps? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg983488.aspx

Comment: Is AppFabric transactional? Can I be 100% sure that two serveres does not insert the same nonse? Also... Can I be 100% sure that the cache is not flushed (eg. when a server stops)?

Comment: AppFabric supports optimistic and pessimistic concurrency models, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790890.aspx for more info on this.

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider memcached (link for use on Azure here: http://blog.smarx.com/posts/memcached-in-windows-azure) so the nonce is stored quickly, then for durability I'd also (asynchonously) store the nonce in table storage.

For performance, at read, I'd perform the check of table storage asynchronously and check that the read should proceed on exit from the main read method.